# How to access a function in child project's build.gradle.kts which is defined in root project's build.gradle.kts

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradlew, dynamicmethod

I have a gradle based project using Kotli DSL. The hierarchy is like the following.

root-project --> child-project

A function is defined in root project's build.gradle.kts file.

`fun printHello() { println("Hello") }`

I want to access this function in the child project's build.gradle.kts file. I tried calling the function but it says unresolved referenece printHello.

Whereas this is given in the gradle documentation that under the **Dynamic methods** sub heading
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html
*

A project has 5 method 'scopes', which it searches for methods:

- The methods of the parent project, recursively up to the root project.*

How can I achieve the same?

I have tried creating a function in root project's build.gradle.kts and invoking it in child project's build.gradle.kts file but it is saying unresolved reference printHello.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation you link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties) is written with a Groovy build script in mind. The approach when using the Kotlin DSL is a bit different because Kotlin is a statically typed language so the compiler must know what functions are defined at compile time.

The analogous way to access functions defined in a parent `build.gradle.kts` file using Kotlin DSL would be (see [partial documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:extra_properties)):

```
// In root build.gradle.kts

// Option 1: Double braces as the return value of the outer lambda gives the property value
val printHello by extra { { println("Hello") } }

// Option 2
extra["printHello"] = { println("Hello") }

// In child build.gradle.kts

// Option 1
val printHello: () -> Unit by project
printHello()

// Option 2
(rootProject.extra["printHello"] as () -> Unit)()
```

None of these is type safe, however, and for that reason I would recommend writing a [precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) or a function inside the `src/main/kotlin` folder of [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) with a Kotlin plugin applied in order to share a snippet of code between projects.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Also, is there any way to access the function in child project’s build.gradle.kts which is defined in root project’s build.gradle.kts just like we normally do it in the same file. I’m asking this because this is mentioned in the documentation that it will search the function upto the root project but I’m unable to achieve the same.

Comment: That documentation you are reading is written specifically for Groovy, which used to be the only language in which you could write a Gradle build script. Because Kotlin is a statically typed language, that can't work in exactly the same way for Kotlin (the compiler needs to know what functions are defined at compile time to do the static type checking). I've described the alternative Kotlin approaches in my answer.

Comment: Oh, that's the case.
Now I understood. Thank you

Comment: Great :) Yes, I could have mentioned that initially